# Fatal error when trying to write scons platform=windows generate_bindings=yes. Following gdnative cpp tutorial

Tags: c++, scons, godot, gdnative

I was following this tutorial on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hK7vOigbLQ),
and on [Github](https://github.com/BastiaanOlij/gdtest). When I run the command `scons platform=windows generate_bindings=yes` inside of `gdtest/godot-cpp` I get the following error. I have VS 2022.

```bash
C:\Users\Antonio>cd gdtest

C:\Users\Antonio\gdtest>cd godot-cpp

C:\Users\Antonio\gdtest\godot-cpp>scons platform=windows generate_bindings=yes
scons: Reading SConscript files ...

scons: *** Path for option target_path does not exist: demo/bin/
File "C:\Users\Antonio\gdtest\godot-cpp\SConstruct.py", line 26, in <module>
```

In my folder path I have:

```
C:\Users\Antonio\gdtest\demo\bin
C:\Users\Antonio\gdtest\godot-cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin
C:\Users\Antonio\gdtest
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin
```

This is my SConstruct file:

```py
import os

opts = Variables([], ARGUMENTS)

# Gets the standard flags CC, CCX, etc.
env = DefaultEnvironment()

# Define our options
opts.Add(EnumVariable('target', "Compilation target", 'debug', ['d', 'debug', 'r', 'release']))
opts.Add(EnumVariable('platform', "Compilation platform", '', ['', 'windows', 'linuxbsd', 'linux', 'osx']))
opts.Add(EnumVariable('p', "Compilation target, alias for 'platform'", '', ['', 'windows', 'linuxbsd', 'linux', 'osx']))
opts.Add(BoolVariable('use_llvm', "Use the LLVM / Clang compiler", 'no'))
opts.Add(PathVariable('target_path', 'The path where the lib is installed.', 'demo/bin/'))
opts.Add(PathVariable('target_name', 'The library name.', 'libgdexample', PathVariable.PathAccept))

# Local dependency paths, adapt them to your setup
godot_headers_path = "godot-cpp/godot-headers/"
cpp_bindings_path = "godot-cpp/"
cpp_library = "libgodot-cpp"

# only support 64 at this time..
bits = 64

# Updates the environment with the option variables.
opts.Update(env)

# Process some arguments
if env['use_llvm']:
    env['CC'] = 'clang'
    env['CXX'] = 'clang++'

if env['p'] != '':
    env['platform'] = env['p']

if env['platform'] == '':
    print("No valid target platform selected.")
    quit()

# For the reference:
# - CCFLAGS are compilation flags shared between C and C++
# - CFLAGS are for C-specific compilation flags
# - CXXFLAGS are for C++-specific compilation flags
# - CPPFLAGS are for pre-processor flags
# - CPPDEFINES are for pre-processor defines
# - LINKFLAGS are for linking flags

# Check our platform specifics
if env['platform'] == "osx":
    env['target_path'] += 'osx/'
    cpp_library += '.osx'
    env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-arch', 'x86_64'])
    env.Append(CXXFLAGS=['-std=c++17'])
    env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-arch', 'x86_64'])
    if env['target'] in ('debug', 'd'):
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-g', '-O2'])
    else:
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-g', '-O3'])

elif env['platform'] in ('linuxbsd', 'linux'):
    env['target_path'] += 'linuxbsd/'
    cpp_library += '.linux'
    env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-fPIC'])
    env.Append(CXXFLAGS=['-std=c++17'])
    if env['target'] in ('debug', 'd'):
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-g3', '-Og'])
    else:
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-g', '-O3'])

elif env['platform'] == "windows":
    env['target_path'] += 'win64/'
    cpp_library += '.windows'
    # This makes sure to keep the session environment variables on windows,
    # that way you can run scons in a vs 2017 prompt and it will find all the required tools
    env.Append(ENV=os.environ)

    env.Append(CPPDEFINES=['WIN32', '_WIN32', '_WINDOWS', '_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS'])
    env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-W3', '-GR'])
    env.Append(CXXFLAGS='/std:c++17')
    if env['target'] in ('debug', 'd'):
        env.Append(CPPDEFINES=['_DEBUG'])
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-EHsc', '-MDd', '-ZI'])
        env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-DEBUG'])
    else:
        env.Append(CPPDEFINES=['NDEBUG'])
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-O2', '-EHsc', '-MD'])

if env['target'] in ('debug', 'd'):
    cpp_library += '.debug'
else:
    cpp_library += '.release'

cpp_library += '.' + str(bits)

# make sure our binding library is properly includes
env.Append(CPPPATH=['.', godot_headers_path, cpp_bindings_path + 'include/', cpp_bindings_path + 'include/core/', cpp_bindings_path + 'include/gen/'])
env.Append(LIBPATH=[cpp_bindings_path + 'bin/'])
env.Append(LIBS=[cpp_library])

# tweak this if you want to use different folders, or more folders, to store your source code in.
env.Append(CPPPATH=['src/'])
sources = Glob('src/*.cpp')

library = env.SharedLibrary(target=env['target_path'] + env['target_name'] , source=sources)

Default(library)

# Generates help for the -h scons option.
Help(opts.GenerateHelpText(env))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its resolved, I add to the SConstruct file on Godot-cpp : `opts.Add(PathVariable('target_path', 'The path where the lib is installed.', 'demo/bin/', PathVariable.PathAccept))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the validator as:
`PathVariable.PathAccept` if it's ok that the target_path doesn't exist when you run SCons.

See:

```
https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#v-PathVariable
```

The default if not specified is:

```
PathVariable.PathExists
Verify that the specified path exists (this the default behavior if no validator is supplied).
```

Comment: I already have `PathVariable.PathAccept` written in my SConstruct file as you can see.

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: You do not have it for target_path, only for target_name.

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Please mark this response as the "answer" :)

Comment: i dont know how to mark as an anwser but I wrote how to resolve

Comment: i got another error, help me https://stackoverflow.com/q/73042849/17992269